# Is it possible for Google Places API to return one single object instead of an array of objects when querying?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm playing around with Google Places API and I was wondering if it were possible to return just one closest result. In the example below I can return all the gyms within a  1km radius which is fine, but if I were to return the closest police station or hospital something for which I'd only want to know the closest one is there a way to do this. It seems the API is returning all the objects within a radius and it can't be altered. I can't seem to find any documentation that highlights this issue, and any attempts I've made still returns all the places in the area.

```
 function GymReport(){

  // Gets the latitude and longitude of a location searched by a user
  $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
  $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());

 var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
 console.log(Lat);

 var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
 console.log(Long);

 var location = {lat: Lat, lng: Long};

   var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
   service.nearbySearch({
       location: location,
       radius: 1000,
       type: ['gym']
     }, callback);
    }
```

Callback Class

```
 function callback(results, status) {

  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      if(marker)
            marker.setMap(null)
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          createMarker(results[i]);<-- This calls the function that will create the markers for the array of results from the API.
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that you can order results of Places nearby search by Prominence or by Distance. By default it is ordered by prominence. You can use the `rankBy` parameter in your code to order by Distance:

> **rankBy** - Specifies the ranking method to use when returning results. Defaults to PROMINENCE. Note that when rankBy is set to DISTANCE, you must specify a location but you cannot specify a radius or bounds.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlaceSearchRequest

Once you get results ordered by distance just get the first element from array which is the nearest place. Have a look at my sample code

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
    type: ['gym']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    //Get the first result, it's the closest one
    createMarker(results[0]);
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Fixed it perfectly. Thanks for getting back to me!